# Is there a better way to create an abstract class that extends another abstract class and adds new features?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, design-patterns, abstract-class

I have an abstract class that has a concrete method `solve`and several abstract methods that are used by `solve`:

```
public abstract class A{
    public void solve(){
       //code for solve

    }

    public abstract void a();
    public abstract void b();
}
```

Then I have another class `B` that extends `A`, reimplements the `solve` methods using the abstract methods from `A` and new ones added (`c,d`). It also has a boolean field that indicates if it has to use the `solve` A or the one from `B`.

```
public abstract class B extends A{
    boolean useA;
    public B(boolean useA){
        this.useA = useA
    }
    public void solve(){
        if(useA) super.solve();
        else // code for solve
    }

    public abstract void c();
    public abstract void d();
}
```

Then I have a concrete class `C` that extends `B`, implements all methods and has a boolean to indicate if solve has to be used or not.

```
public class C extends B{

    public C(boolean useA){
        super(useA);
    }

    ... //code for a,b,c and d
}
```

Is there any way to do this better? I think that maybe it's not following the principles of OOP.

Comment: I don't see a problem.  If you're not finding yourself duplicating code, then you're on the right path.  But this is too small an example, you'll need to build up your classes and see any issues with this strategy.

Comment: follow this link to learn inheritance : https://www.javatpoint.com/inheritance-in-java

Comment: Does your design make sense for your specific problem?  If so, then it is probably at least valid.  I would comment that less class hierarchy is probably desirable, as it can lead to a maintenance nightmare later on.

Comment: The code you posted won't work as you expect/intend it to. You are calling the solve method in the constructor already. If you want to make it conditional what version of the solve method will be used you need to put the `if(useA)` condition into the solve method and branch it from there. Something like a "conditional method declaration" as in "if useA is true don't override the method" doesn't exist.

Comment: Since sub-classes are adding/modifying behavior perhaps consider the [decorator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern).

Comment: As @TimBiegeleisen alludes, the devil is in the details. Can you make your question more specific to a real context (not A's, B's, etc.). Object classes have their design power in being easy to understand in a context of a problem they solve, so leaving those details out makes answering design questions too theoretical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that the best solution for OOP is sometimes heavily over-engineered. So in some cases the solution which takes the least amount of work will be the best.

Also it is really hard to judge in this case. While it is good that you tried to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example, it lacks the most important information about what should inherit what: **the purpose of each class**. You could for example imagine that it might make sense to split your class `B` into two, where one does and the other doesn't override `solve()`, but if that is a good idea can only be decided to ask the right questions about the purpose of each class.

I suspect that you are asking these questions because you want to know the best way to reuse code in your classes. If that is the case: **don't**. Taken from [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_(object-oriented_programming)#Code_reuse) wikipedia article:

> In most quarters, class inheritance for the sole purpose of code reuse has fallen out of favor. The primary concern is that implementation inheritance does not provide any assurance of polymorphic substitutability—an instance of the reusing class cannot necessarily be substituted for an instance of the inherited class. An alternative technique, explicit delegation, requires more programming effort, but avoids the substitutability issue. In C++ private inheritance can be used as a form of implementation inheritance without substitutability. Whereas public inheritance represents an "is-a" relationship and delegation represents a "has-a" relationship, private (and protected) inheritance can be thought of as an "is implemented in terms of" relationship.

Answer (score 2):

Some already mentioned the decorator pattern, and there is the strategy pattern too.

However one might use lambdas for injecting some handlers.

Handlers might be done using *public service / protected requirement*:

```
class A {
    public final f() {
       ...
       onF(x, y);
    }

    protected abstract void onF(X x, Y y);
}
```

Solution complexes often are better of *without inheritance*, but as field,  delegating to a field.

In that the answer of @LonelyNeuron gives good arguments.

In short: when in doubt, code it out first, and refactor it to some elegant model. Separating concerns and such.